# Is is appropriate to put this on a shirt

Tags: grammar

Is is appropriate to put this on a shirt: 自分を信じて

Comment: Do you know what it means?  What meaning are you trying to express? Do you expect others to know what it means?

Comment: Also, though the meaning is different, a Japanese person would be far more likely to say 頑張れ.  Though this is often translated as "good luck" in English, the meaning is actually a lot closer to what you probably want to express:  "go for it" or "strive!!!".  Or it's uttered in circumstances where in English we might say, "You can do it!!!"

Comment: Trying to communicate “Believe in yourself” it will go on a Brazilian jiu-jitsu gi

Comment: If you’re question is “whether this is strange-sounding Japanese and make a Japanese speaking person laugh”, then the answer is no, it’s grammatical and natural Japanese. Whether it expresses the intended meaning is another thing.

Comment: @dvx2718 Exactly, hence the reason I suggested 頑張れ.  That simple phrase I think captures well the intended meaning.  But, it's certainly not the only such phrase, just the first one that came to mind for me.

Comment: https://store.shopping.yahoo.co.jp/synthese-records/jibun-tshirts.html#

Comment: It's one of the better ones of the tattoo or shirt design ideas I've seen here. I wouldn't laugh when I see it printed on someone's shirt.

Comment: @A.Ellett It's normal not to print any message on judo uniforms, but if you must print some message on a T-shirt or judo uniform, 自分を信じて actually looks more natural and better than 頑張れ.

Comment: @naruto Thank you for the feed back.

Answer (score 3):

自分を信じて is natural as something to print at least on a casual T-shirt. When it comes to jiujitsu-gi, however, I haven't seen a judo-gi with a message on it in the first place, so it might appear a bit strange to Japanese eyes. Still, if you really need to print something, 自分を信じて is not a strange message at all. It conveys the intended meaning ("Believe in yourself") well.